# If you have 100 spheres packed into a sphere shape, how many will be on the surface?

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

My question is more about ratios. I'm wondering is there a calculator or formula I can input an X number of Spheres. If the spheres are packed in a spherical shape what is the ratio of The interior spheres compared to the spheres on the surface?
Thanks

Comment: Does anyone suggest a better way to ask this question? The answers so far do not address the question. I am not trying to pack spheres into a larger sphere. I just wanna know if you accumulate 100 identical spheres into a relatively sphere shape, how many spheres will be on the surface. It doesn’t need to be exact, it can be within one or two. I realize it will slightly change when going from hexagonal packing to cubic packing. Please help thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is an unsolved problem. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing_in_a_sphere) is a description for $X\le 12$.

Also, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952543/optimally-filling-a-3d-sphere-with-smaller-spheres) other thread for more information on the subject

Comment: Really! Unsolved? I guess I'm asking the right questions. I can't believe that,  it seems like such a simple thing. Now I'm really interested. I mean, I can grab a handfuls of magnetic balls and figure it out but after while that gets hard to keep track. There's got to be a calculator already designed for this.

Comment: Math is choke full of unsolved problems which seem even _simpler_ than that.

Comment: @BillAlsept Maybe you want to start playing with [Kepler's Conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KeplerConjecture.html)

Comment: @caverac I just realize this answer does not answer my question. I am specifically asking about the ratio between surface spears and interior spheres when they’re all packed into a sphere shape. For example, take 100 spheres impact them into a sphere shape. How many are on the surface compared to how many are on the interior? Take the same question again for 150 spheres packed in to a sphere shape and so on. There has to be a formula or calculator that could do this.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have $N$ spheres, with radius 1.

Suppose you pack them together in a sphere with radius $R$. Random sphere packings have a density of about 64%, so you can use this to approximate what $R$ would be.

$$0.64 \frac43 \pi R^3 = N \frac43 \pi 1^3\\
0.64 R^3 = N\\
R = \left( \frac{N}{0.64} \right)^{\frac13}$$

To find the number of spheres on the surface, we can consider it a circle packing of the area $4\pi (R-1)^2$. I subtracted $1$, the radius of the small spheres, because the centres of the surface spheres are located on a sphere of that radius, and that is where the packing takes place.

Random circle packings have a density of about 82%, so packing an area of $4\pi (R-1)^2$ with circles of area $\pi 1^2=\pi$ we get:

$$N_s = 0.82 \frac{4\pi (R-1)^2}{\pi} = 3.28 (R-1)^2$$

Substituting $R$ gives the formula:
$$N_s = 3.28 \left(\left( \frac{N}{0.64} \right)^{\frac13}-1 \right)^2$$

This is just a very rough approximation that is not applicable to relatively small numbers of spheres, but then again the problem is somewhat loosely defined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am traveling today and have not tried this yet. I’m curious how many surface spheres would you have if you packed 100 spheres together? Also how many surface spheres would you have if you packed 75 spheres together?

Comment: @BillAlsept I have improved my answer so that it is a bit closer to reality for the smaller number of spheres that you are interested in. It is still very rough, and the percentages I used are for random packings. With careful placement of the spheres you can improve on that so this approximation will then be further off the mark.

Comment: i’m still having trouble getting this to match actual modeling. Could you please tell me the answer to the two scenarios I mentioned above. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

The maximum density of an infinite number of congruent identical spheres packed within a larger sphere is 0.74048... or Pi/(sqrt(18)), as stated in the Kepler Conjecture, partially proven by Gauss and not formally proven by Thomas C. Hale until 2014.

The Kepler Conjecture states that “no arrangement of equally sized spheres filling space has a greater average density than that of the cubic close packing (face-centered cubic) and hexagonal close packing arrangements.”

I actually worked this out myself (but didn’t prove it) by calculating how many spheres could fit into a regular tetrahedral container and a square pyramidal container.

When the number of spheres got well into the millions, the values converged at .074048...

I still have the Excel spreadsheets that I used to do the calculations.

Comment: The formula for the density of congruent identical spheres within a tetrahedral container (four equilateral triangles) is: D = (4/3*PI()*(n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6)/(((((2*n)-2)+(2*3^0.5))^3)/(6*2^0.5)) (Excel compatible) where D = density and n = the number of spheres along the base of the tetrahedron. For example, if n = 1000, D = 0.7411 The formula for the density of congruent identical spheres packed within a square pyramidal container (consisting of a square base and four equilateral triangles) is: D = ((2/9)*n*(1+n)*(1+2*n)*Pi()*r^3)/((2*(1+2^0.5*n)^3)/3) So if n = 1000, D = 0.7400